# Excel VBA Importing data from Word Documents with inconsistent formattting

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to obtain values and tolerances from a bunch of specification sheets (word documents). The specification sheets are all very similar but the formatting within their tables is inconsistent.

For instance, sometimes the values and tolerances for power will be listed in a certain format which Excel will import as:             +2%      339         kW [3] 4       -2%

Other times, the values and tolerances for power will be listed in a different format which Excel will import as: 247±2% kW [3]5

Besides editing all of the documents to make the formatting consistent, is there any way that I can use VBA to extract the values and tolerances from a variety of different formats?

Comment: The brute force method would be to identify some unique (or hierarchical) property of each distinct format and write a sub routine for each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start first with identifying the different unique formats available. Hopefully you only have a couple of formats. And use a RegEx within VBA. You should be able to write a pattern that will match all the different format variations